# How do i add single answer multiple choices question in SurveyMonkey?

Tags: survey, surveymonkey

I thought this should be super-easy but I guess SurveyMonkey didnt want to make this easy for their own reasons.

I tried adding multiple radio buttons answers but I am able to select them all and I cant see any settings which makes it required and as a single answer!

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

You probably selected `Checkboxes` instead of `Multiple Choice`.

If you want to create a question where the respondent can only make one selection by default, you're looking for `Multiple Choice`:

[image]